# Not showing decimals properly

Tags: c#, numbers, double, decimal

```
        Console.Write("Please type in the first floating point number: ");
        double floating_1 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.Write("Please type in the second floating point number: ");
        double floating_2 = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());

        double product = floating_1 * floating_2;
        double difference = floating_1 - floating_2;
        double sum = floating_1 + floating_2;

        Console.WriteLine("The product of the two floating point numbers is: " + product + "\nThe sum of the two floating point numbers is: " + sum + "\nThe difference between the two floating point numbers is: " + difference);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

I have this piece of code. Whenever i execute the program, the decimals aren't showing correctly (Like the number: 45.23 will be shows as 4523).

Comment: what is your input value? Are you separating with comma or point?

Comment: I am seperating with a point.

Comment: Where is the problem..can you elaborate..??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess would be that your country settings are set to a country that uses , instead of . do determine decimals.

try entering for example 14,5 instead of 14.5 and see what happens.

c# parses number input and formats number output in accordance to your country-defaults

Comment: Thanks and yes you were right. The country settings caused the issues. Using the , instead of . worked for me.